# Gap in right margin of page won't go away

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm building a new project using reactJS, nodeJS, and react-bootstrap. When setting up my landing page. There is a gap in the margin on the right side of the page that won't go away, no matter what I try.

.I've tried including the meyer's reset css file in the index.html.
.I've tried setting margins, borders, and padding on the Body element to  zero.
.I've tried setting my Container to width: 100%.
.I've tried resizing the background image.
.I've tried including the bootstrap 4 cdn in my index.html.

App.js

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import LandingPage from './components/landingpage';
import Header from './components/header';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>

          <Header/>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={LandingPage}/>
          </Switch>
          <Footer/>

      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

App.css

```css
/* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}*/

body {
  background-image: url('./images/background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  /*background-size: cover;*/
  font-family: 'Courgette', cursive;
  color: beige;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.courgette {
  font-family: 'Courgette', cursive;
}

.lobster {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}
```

header.js

```
import React from "react";
import './header.css';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


const Header = () => {
    return(
      <Container className='header'>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Link href="#">
              <img className='hamburgermenu' src={require('./../../images/navbaricon.png')} alt='Hamburger Menu Icon'/>
            </Link>
          </Col>

          <Col>
            <h1>MDNight</h1>
          </Col>

          <Col>
            <p>Hello!</p>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    )
}


export default Header;
```

header.css

```css
.header{
    background-color: maroon;
    margin: 0;
}

.hamburgermenu {
    height: 80px;
    width: auto;
}
```

The header is supposed to extend to the edge of the page, but it does not.

Comment: is it possible for to provide fiddle link with working code?

Comment: what have you seen in the inspection tools?

Comment: https://github.com/dscherer21/mdnight here is my github.

Answer (score 0):

There is any margin gap in the application.